# Track selection of user location annotation in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, userlocation

I have an iPhone app that zooms to the nearest city of the user's location and I want the user to be able to double tap on the **userLocation annotation** and have the map zoom into about a block or so.

How do I get the `userLocation` annotation to recognize that it's being tapped?

Comment: did you try my code as i suggested??

Comment: Not yet but I will right now!

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)mapView2
{
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = mapView2.annotation;
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
          // this is where you can find the annotation type is whether it is userlocation or not...
     }
}
```

the above method is a delegate method and you need to add `MKMapViewDelegate` in your interface file

Comment: Well MapAnnotation isn't a type. MKAnnotation is but whenever I try to declare the MKAnnotation object I get an error at says Unknown Type 'MKAnnotation'

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in Swift 4:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        // You tapped on the user location
    }
}
```